# Turn long list of items in Highcharts legend into dropdown

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I [have a graph](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/extras/arctic_sea_ice_graph.php) with some 40 items as separate lines. Now, I need to add the functionality of turning on/off or highlighting any of these via legend/menu/dropdown list.

Normally, when the legend is turned on, I can click on any item and turn it on/off there. However, the very long legend really skews (the beauty of) my graph. Is there any way to achieve the same thing (turning on/off) with a drop-down menu? That could be visually much more attractive.

Otherwise, last resort, a simple button "turn on/off" legend need to suffice then (like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/3Bh7b/1/), although the "turn on" doesn't work).

[image: Highcharts graph with long legend]

```
// turn legend on/off with HTML button
function(chart){
    $('#updateLegend').click(function (e) {
        var legend = chart.legend; 

        if(legend.display) {
            legend.group.hide();
            legend.box.hide();
            legend.display = false;
        } else {

            legend.group.show();
            legend.box.show();
            legend.display = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Here you don't have a **`legend.box`** therefore it doesn't work. Comment the hide and show of the **`box`** and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/3Bh7b/118/

Comment: Simple demo of dropdown legend: http://jsfiddle.net/b8chchjo/

Comment: Do you need to group the series into some category like "all in 1980-1989"? Also, +1 just because that is a beautiful graph.

Comment: @wergeld: No grouping needed, although, this could be an interesting feature. And yes, I like that graph very much too... :-)

Comment: It is a very nice implementation of the NYT graph - well done.  If I were doing this, I would want to have a pop up with the ability to check boxes for which series to show/hide, personally, rather than clicking a single series at a time with no indication of which series are visible/hidden.  If you search "highcharts external legend" you should find enough info to follow up with, and there are plenty of ways to handle the pop up/drop down technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prepare dynamic dropdown legend, based on series. Only what you need is loop over each of serie and push as option to select. Then add event change, where you show/hide serie.

```
var $customLegend = $('#customLegend').append('<select id="customSelect"></select>').find('select'),
        $option,
        serie;

    $customLegend.append('<option>Select serie</option>');

    $.each(chart.series, function(i, serie){
        $customLegend.append('<option>' + serie.name + '</option>');
    });

    $customLegend.change(function(){

        $option = $(this).val();

        serie = chart.get($option);

        if(serie.visible) {
            serie.hide();
        } else {
            serie.show();
        }
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8chchjo/